# Wordpress NextGen Custom Template

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I have a Image Gallery in NextGen and i want to show it on a page but problem is whenever i am loading image gallery with custom template it isn't loading here how is what i did, first i have a page `homepage.php` and at some place i added this code to show the gallery:

```
<?php
      $NextG = new NextGEN_Shortcodes;
      echo $NextG->show_gallery( array("id"=>1,"images"=>5,"template"=>"myshow") );
?>
```

my template file `myshow.php` contains this :

```
<ul id="slideshow">
  <!-- Thumbnails -->
  <?php foreach ( $images as $image ) : ?>

    <li>
      <?php if ( !$image->hidden ) { ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $image->imageURL ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" />
      <?php } ?>
    </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Now Template file named `myshow.php`  is located in `wordpress\wp-content\themes\nggallery`

and when i run the page it returns the images but it used default template what is wrong am i putting the wrong name??? am i putting the Template in wrong directory?? or is there something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got the answer i only have to put right name prefix for my file `"gallery-<mytemplatename>"` so in above case it will be `gallery-myshow.php`